# How do i disable having two audio inputs in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I know that Windows Vista let you have only one input. How do i make that happen in Windows 7? I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: What do you mean by one input? Do you mean in Recording Devices, you have one microphone listed in Vista and 2/more listed in 7?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about Recording Devices, I can think of two options -

1. Right click on any of the input device and click Disable (and select your default device)
2. Install the right audio drivers. Taking an example, if you have a laptop with 2 Microphones, installing the drivers would utilize these devices, the right way and only one device would be listed

(If you have an additional external audio input device connected, you may have to manually disable it or physically disconnect it)